# customer's password not displayed in email templates magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento, passwords, email-templates

I have a problem with displaying the password in email (account_new.html)

```
<strong>Email</strong>: {{var customer.email}}<br/>
<strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}<p>
```

After registration password is not displayed in the template.
How can I fix this? I use magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: It seems fix to 1.9.3.0, no ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145999/24845

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento 1.9 version has problem to send password in emails.
and not set var values under `{{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}`

There is one solution to send password in email

Open the core file or extend as you like AccountController.php, 
find the function `createPostAction()` on line 285 or find

```
$customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
```

just comment it like this

```
// $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
```

also do it in other places as on line 809, 954

now it sends the password to customer new account email.

## Other method

open or extend the custom model file

magento\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php

find the function

```
public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
{
    $this->setData('password', null);
    $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
    return $this;
}
```

comment out `// $this->setData('password', null);`

```
public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
{
    // $this->setData('password', null);
    $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: ti's working, 
but when register customer so link redirect on home page .so it's go to customer dashboard. How to redirect customer dashboard. ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because password will be stored in encrypted format.
It is in irreversible format.

Sending the password in mail is not the best practice.
You have to follow up the best practices, Even though if your client is insisting you to do this thing. You have to convince him to not go with this kind of thing.

As customer had given the password while the registration process. Obviously he knows his password. If he forgotten then he can use the forgot password to get his new password.

Anyway I will not suggest you here to send the password through email, Sorry.

Comment: You're correct that it's stupid to send plaintext passwords, but Magento does keep the password available for the remainder of the signup request. So an email sent as part of registration can access the plain text password variable...and the default behaviour does just that...unless Magento changed the behaviour in 1.9.1.

Comment: It's fix in 1.9.3.0, no ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840703/customers-password-not-displayed-in-email-templates-magento-1-9-1-0/31262786#comment68488866_28840703